# Display the data stored in SharePoint List, on page in table format and to put filter on table columns on the page for filtering the data

Tags: javascript, filter, sharepoint-list

I need to display the data stored in SharePoint List on page in table format. Also I need to put filter on table columns on the page for filtering the data. Below is the columns of the List:[Table Coulmns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpQTq.png)

I need to put filter on Month, Date, Theme and Recommended Audience.

Comment: Ok bro but did you try anything?

Comment: Actually I am new to Javascript and Sharepoint.So I don't have idea,how to proceed.

 I need to perform two  tasks:

1. Fetch the data from Sharepoint list and dispaly the data on page.
2.Need the filter on above given columns(Month, Date, Theme and Recommended Audience).